# How to install new packages in texlive?

Tags: texlive, installing, document-classes, tlmgr, novel

I am pretty new to latex and texlive.

I want to install the `novel` class from this [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/novel) repository, but I can’t figure it out.

when I try installing it with the `tlmgr` command such as

```
tlmgr install /macros/luatex/latex/novel
```

I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: if you used a default installation novel would be installed already. to add it with `tlmgr` you would use `tlmgr install novel` (you don't need the files from ctan, and don't supply a path) or if you are using a system texlive you would use `apt-get` or whichever package manager you use.

Comment: as `tlmgr` is in `/usr/bin` I guess you are using the linux system tex in which case on debian/ubuntu etc you probably want `sudo apt install texlive-extra` not `tlmgr`

Comment: When you use texlive from debian/Ubuntu you cannot use tlmgr to install latex packages (debian disables it). You can use a tool like `apt-file` to figure out which Ubuntu package contains the latex package you wanted. Remember though, latex from a Linux dist is often not up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you both for your comments, I figured it out. I installed both the Ubuntu Texlive distribution and the default installation from the [Texlive `tar.gz`](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz).

So what I did was simply removing every Texlive distribution available on my system, and then reinstalling the default and most up-to-date version of Texlive distribution from [the Texlive website](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html), and then just followed the [full installation documentation](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation).

Now everything works, and indeed the `novel` class is by default installed in the distribution; no need to reinstall it.