# tlmgr update --self bailing out with user mode

Tags: texlive, updating, tlmgr, texlive2022

I’ve been using Vanilla TeX live from upstream, and I did in the past `tlmgr update --all` and `--self` without any issue.

However, now, something new shows up (even though it doesn’t seem new when I look on the internet), that is `user mode`. Basically, I have this error message:

```
$ sudo tlmgr update -self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

So I read the documentation, run `tlmgr init-usertree` but it was already initialized:

```
$ tlmgr init-usertree

tlmgr: user mode database already set up in
tlmgr:   /home/louisvgn/texmf/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
tlmgr: not overwriting it.
```

Now, all I want in the end is to be able to update `--all`, but I don’t know how I can do that this it always gives me the first error message telling me `user mode not initialized`.

Down the line, though, I’d like to understand what this is all about, and how one can override it in order to install/update system-wide.

Comment: you are using tlmgr from the system tex not upstream texlive from tug

Comment: either use the debian system texlive and update using apt or use a tug texlive and updtate using tlmgr

Comment: er as you asked a year ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616493/1090

Comment: is your tug texlive installed under sudo or under your account? In the latter case sudo in your first code block is wrong

Comment: Yes exactly, as I stated in a year ago, I installed the TUG texlive and was able to use tlmgr without issue. It is no longer the case though.

Comment: when I do which here is what I get: `which tlmgr` = `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`; `sudo which tlmgr` = `/usr/bin/tlmgr`. I don’t if that says that it’s installed under sudo or under my account. I believe I installed it in `home`

Comment: so as I said, if you use sudo you are using the system  tex. don't do that, use the one you installed

Answer (score 1):

You want to update `/usr/local/texlive/2022` so you need to use `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`

apparently `/usr/local/texlive/2022` is writable under your account, so you do not need `sudo` If you had installed it under sudo you would need to update under sudo but should first set the PATH to start `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux` you have only set that under your account.

However

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

should update your copy of texlive.

The above will definitly not give the warning in the question about `/usr/share/...` (the system texlive) However if you originally installed tug texlive under sudo and do not have write access to update, you could give yourself access or update under sudo using

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self --all
```

so it uses the right one.

Comment: well I set the path `$ set PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux`, but it still doesn’t work when I do `tlmgr update --self`. I’m not sure I understand what’s wrong.

Comment: @Louis.vgn you need that at the _front_ of your path not the entire path your comment under the question shows you had already set the path. You can not get the `Debian` message that you show in the question from the tlmgr in  `/usr/local`

Comment: I don’t understand. What do you mean?

Comment: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux`  means you can only run commands from that directory all other linux commands will not be found, you want `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` so you keep the existing path but you say above `which tlmgr = /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr` so you have already done that and set the path in your account (but not the path used by sudo)

Comment: So what command should I do now to set the right path so that it can update? I still don’t get it.

Comment: @Louis.vgn as I say you have set the path already so `tlmgr update --self --all` should work (it certainly will not give the error in the question). If you installed under sudo and can not write to /usr/local/texlive/2022 make that writable by you or use `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self --all`

Comment: Using this command `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self` worked, but then what does it mean? It means that it is install with Debian or that it is from TUG? Because I am pretty sure I installed it from TUG, not Debian. Also, when doing `tlmgr update --self --alll` it still gives me the same error that I put in the question.

Comment: @Louis.vgn `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/` is the one from tug, for the rest it's really just generic path and sudo issues whch are not really on topic here. ` tlmgr update --self --all` would not give the debian warning in the question if (as you said in comments)  `which tlmgr` gave the path to the tug version.